How do we read Kafka topics in a given time range efficiently?
I need to read messages in given timerange from kafka topic. I have read docs, which says we can use offsetsForTimes to get offset for a msg with earliest timestamp >= inputTimeStamp, and can start reading from there.
Used below implementation based on my understanding
private void readInRange(long startTime, long endTime)   
{
    List<PartitionInfo> partitionInfos = consumer.partitionsFor(myTopic);
    List<TopicPartition> topicPartitions = new ArrayList<>();
    for (PartitionInfo partitionInfo : partitionInfos) {
        topicPartitions.add(new TopicPartition(partitionInfo.topic(), partitionInfo.partition()));
    }
    Map<TopicPartition, Long> partitionTimestampMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (TopicPartition topicPartition : topicPartitions) {
        partitionTimestampMap.put(topicPartition, startTime);
    }
    Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndTimestamp> partitionOffsetMap = consumer.offsetsForTimes(partitionTimestampMap);
    for (TopicPartition topicPartition : topicPartitions) {
        consumer.assign(Collections.singletonList(topicPartition));
        consumer.seek(topicPartition, partitionOffsetMap.get(topicPartition).offset());
        boolean running = true;
        while (running) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> consumerRecords = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(2000));
            if (Objects.isNull(consumerRecords) && consumerRecords.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord : consumerRecords) {
                if (consumerRecord.timestamp() > endTime) {
                    running = false;
                    break;
                }

                // processing of records
            }
        }
    }
}

@Bean
public KafkaConsumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer() {

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "myConsumerGroupId");
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    return new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
    }

Approach :

traverse each partition of topic
find start offset to read from.
keep reading and exist once recordTimeStamp > endTime

Slow Execution of consuming records  :
We have 4 partitions of the topic, but still we are consuming as if we have single partition because we have only one KafkaConsumer(one application), hence not able to get scaling benefit of consuming from multiple partitions at once, using apache-kafka library for this use-case.
How can we use multiple consumers(say equal to num_partitions) such that they poll parallelly from each partition & process records independently, once all records from every partition is consumed, we club results & process further.
Basically multi-consumer single-application model for parallel processing of records on different partitions ?

consumer.assign can be given multiple partitions rather than just one at a time. Otherwise, you'd need to use threads around the poll/while loop for each partition

@OneCricketeer, If we use consumer.assign with multiple partitions polling will still be happen based on max.records.poll, and we will still be consuming from one partition at a time if records present in 1 partition > max.records.poll, Also for my use-case, It would be difficult to know when to stop poll, as now we read from multiple partition at a time, say partition-0 has no events anymore and partition-1 has, & we exit the loop based on our first fetch call which went to partition-0.

If you assign/start multiple threads to different partitions, it will poll from them all in parallel, and each thread would stop on the timestamp condition as you've defined.

You mean to say like instantiate one consumer instance (inside one thread) for each partition and then each thread can stop on timestamp condition. Would there be any implications of making multiple KafkaConsumer instances in one application, also since we have assigned  properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG,"myConsumerGroupId"); to each of our consumer would it be safer to remove this in case of multiple consumers with each assigned to diff partition.

Group ids are only shared when using consumer.subscribe, in my experience. In the Javadoc - Manual partition assignment does not use group coordination, so consumer failures will not cause assigned partitions to be rebalanced. Each consumer acts independently even if it shares a groupId with another consumer. It also mentions that you can have one KafkaConsumer per thread.

got it, i'll try to implement one KafkaConsumer with one thread for each partition an see f there's any performance improvement.

@OneCricketeer, We have consumer attached to each partitions, & since group-id would be null here, we cannot use auto-commit without group id, so should we manual commitSync after processing records on each consumer.poll and than too on partition leve ?

Committing manually is always recommended to ensure data is processed successfully. But the group wouldn't be "null" since the ID is still needed to be used for the consumer_offsets topic storage. The ID just isn't used for rebalancing if any consumer has a fatal exception

@OneCricketeer, in that case Can we assign all kafkaConsumers on each thread a same group.id while creation here public KafkaConsumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer(), & just use the normal offset commit method : consumer.commitSync() for committing offset for a particular partition.

I believe that should work
